# VBScript alternative to PHP's preg_match

Tags: vbscript

I need to rewrite the following PHP snippet (which filters out any non-numeric characters from the supplied string);

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $old_string)
```

into VBScript. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function repNum(myString)
    Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp
    With RegularExpressionObject
        .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    repNum = RegularExpressionObject.Replace(myString, "")
    Set RegularExpressionObject = nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Setting `IgnoreCase` is pointless in this case as there aren't upper-/lowercase digits, and the expression matches anything else.